# Match text not surrounded with {{ }} python regex

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

I am trying to replace text within html files that are part of my angular 2 project.

I want to only replace hard-coded text that is not within {{ }}

My current code is able to find all the text in all these html files but I am having issues isolating the text that I want to replace.

Here is my current regex statement

```
print(re.findall('([^\s:|])+', child.string))
```

and here is a sample of its matches:

```
['{{data.name}}']
['{{data.name}}']
['SITE', '{{data.sitenum}}']
['SITE', '{{data.sitenum}}']
[]
[]
['CSC', '{{data.cscnum}}']
['CSC', '{{data.cscnum}}']
['{{data.alertcnt}}']
['{{data.alertcnt}}']
```

I would like to match 'SITE' and 'CSC' but none of the other ones that I'm currently matching.

Comment: Try  `filter(None, re.findall(r'{{.*?}}|([^\s:|]+)', child.string))`

Comment: Do you want to replace _only_ 'SITE' and 'CSC' or some other tags as well?

Comment: Ah, if you need to replace, why did you use `findall`? Use `re.sub(r'{{.*?}}|([^\s:|]+)', lambda x: "something" if x.group(1) else x.group(0), child.string)`

Comment: @DYZ Ya I want to replace arbitrary text that's not in {{}}

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I was planning on using replace eventually and just using findall to test my regex.

Comment: But it is not clear what exactly you need to get in the end. Please check my suggestion and let know     if it works for you.

Comment: Right, I suppose I may want to use find and then replace because I want to create a key from the matched text and replace that with an angular pipe.

So I'd want to take CSC, make it lowercase then replace that in the original html with {{ 'csc' | myFilter }}

Comment: In my above suggestion change the lambda to `lambda x: "{{{{ '{0}' | myFilter }}}}".format(x.group(1).lower()) if x.group(1) else x.group(0)`

Comment: So, does that work for you? See a [Python snippet](https://ideone.com/Ge4msw).

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to take the match insert it into a new file because I want to create a file with key/value pairs of the replacement. I think I'm going to need to do a lot more in the lambda